# Inserting tracking pixel into html email newsletter

Tags: javascript, html-email

I am working on a new email template for our marketing, the ad agency have asked for us to insert a tracking pixel.

How would I go about inserting a tracking pixel into our email marketing template?

The tracking pixel is a snippet of javascript which doesn't have any effects to the styling of the email. Would this code simply be places into the head tag?

Or is it more to it than that? If it can't go in the head tag, how can the performance of the email be tracked by our ad agency?

Comment: http://skillcrush.com/2012/07/19/tracking-pixel/

Comment: It is not a snippet of javascript. From my understanding it's just an image you insert in your code, so the tracking stuff should be done server side (every time a new ip address asks for that image, register it as a "new user has read the email" event)

Comment: Just a thought here, but many mail clients won't even request the images unless the user allows it. Another trick would be inaudible sound files... Just an idea, facebook's been using that tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for instance a 1px by 1px transparent spacer.gif with tracking URL or ALT which you can identify in your analytics software.